# WordPress (non-Docker) cannot connect to MySQL (Docker)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, docker

Actually I'm just moving my database into Docker container.

Here's my MySQL docker-compose configuration:

```yaml
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 336:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

WordPress configuration (non-Docker):

```php
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'wordpress' );

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password' );

/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost:336' );

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define( 'DB_CHARSET', 'utf8' );

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define( 'DB_COLLATE', '' );
```

I can connect to MySQL with command `mysql -u root -P 336 -h localhost -p` on host machine, but the WordPress shows:

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1698): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' in /var/www/dev/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1626

> `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Please help, thanks!

Comment: If you change mysql port docker-compose to ```3306:3306``` and ```define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost:3306' );``` , what do you get ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to create the "wordpress" db first used in your Wordpress settings. You can create one direct from docker-composer or you can use the mysql cli.

```
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 336:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

Comment: emmm, I've already imported the database with docker exec, db `wordpress` is already there...

Comment: and root user has access to it? are you sure you can access it via mysql cli?